# Using a function within a function coded in dplyr

Tags: r, function, debugging, dplyr

I want to use a function within a function with column names coded in `dplyr` as below which throw the following error:

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) :    Column `G` is
>   unknown

Code:

```
# rm(list = ls())

set.seed(12345)
Y  <- rnorm(10)
Env <- paste0("E", rep(1:2, each = 5))
Gen <- paste0("G", rep(1:5, times = 2))
df1 <- data.frame(Y, Env, Gen)

fn1 <- function(.data, .gen, .env, .y){

  Y   <- deparse(substitute(.y))
  G   <- deparse(substitute(.gen))
  E   <- deparse(substitute(.env))

  ge_means <-
    .data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!!rlang::sym(G), !!rlang::sym(E)) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(!!rlang::sym(Y)))

  return(list(
    ge_means = ge_means
    ))
}

fn1(
    .data = df1
  , .gen  = Gen
  , .env  = Env
  , .y    = Y
)


fn2 <- function(.data, .gen, .env, .y){

  Y   <- deparse(substitute(.y))
  G   <- deparse(substitute(.gen))
  E   <- deparse(substitute(.env))

  ge_means1 <- 
      fn1(
          .data = .data
        , .gen  = G
        , .env  = E
        , .y    = Y
      )$ge_mean

  return(list(
    ge_means1 = ge_means1
  ))
}


fn2(
    .data = df1
  , .gen  = Gen
  , .env  = Een
  , .y    = Y
)
```

Comment: Please do not post destructive commands like `rm(...)` that will wipe out readers' workspace.

Comment: A reminder that we would rather you did not add how much you will appreciate answers to all of your posts. In ordinary conversation this is a politeness, but when [adding to editors' workloads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it), it is rather the opposite. Would you kindly refrain in the future?

Comment: Thank you for making your more recent questions more succinct. This is a definite improvement, and will reduce the amount of work required on your posts. I would also offer the following advice: the `backtick device` adds inline code formatting suitable for short samples of code, logs, errors and console IO. It carries a certain semantic meaning, and is not a general highlighter.

Comment: Thus, if you wish to talk about general software, services and programming languages, these _do not_ need code formatting, since their names (Python, Ubuntu, GitHub etc) are not themselves code. They are essentially _proper nouns_ and so just need to be rendered in the correct case (usually initial capital). Libraries are in a middle ground, since their names are typed into a package manager, and so they _could_ be regarded as IO. However, if in doubt, don't add the formatting - it's confusing and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `enquo` instead of `deparse/substitute` and then converting back to symbol using `sym`

```
fn1 <- function(.data, .gen, .env, .y){

  Y   <- enquo(.y)
  G   <- enquo(.gen)
  E   <- enquo(.env)

  ge_means <-
    .data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!! G, !! E) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(!! Y))

  return(list(
    ge_means = ge_means
    ))
}

fn1(
    .data = df1
  , .gen  = Gen
  , .env  = Env
  , .y    = Y
)
```

-output

```
#$ge_means
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups: Gen [?]
#   Gen    Env      Mean
#   <fctr> <fctr>  <dbl>
# 1 G1     E1      0.586
# 2 G1     E2     -1.82 
# 3 G2     E1      0.709
# 4 G2     E2      0.630
# 5 G3     E1     -0.109
# 6 G3     E2     -0.276
# 7 G4     E1     -0.453
# 8 G4     E2     -0.284
# 9 G5     E1      0.606
#10 G5     E2     -0.919
```

---

For the 'fn2' convert the '.y', '.gen', '.env' to quosure with `enquo` and then evaluate the arguments of 'fn1' using `!!`

```
fn2 <- function(.data, .gen, .env, .y){
      Y   <- enquo(.y)
      G   <- enquo(.gen)
      E   <- enquo(.env)

     ge_means1 <-  fn1(
          .data, 
         .gen = !! G,  
         .env = !! E,   
         .y = !! Y    
      )$ge_mean

      return(list(
    ge_means1 = ge_means1
  ))

}


fn2(
    .data = df1,
   .gen  = Gen,
   .env  = Env,
   .y    = Y
)
```

-output

```
#$ge_means1
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups: Gen [?]
#   Gen    Env      Mean
#   <fctr> <fctr>  <dbl>
# 1 G1     E1      0.586
# 2 G1     E2     -1.82 
# 3 G2     E1      0.709
# 4 G2     E2      0.630
# 5 G3     E1     -0.109
# 6 G3     E2     -0.276
# 7 G4     E1     -0.453
# 8 G4     E2     -0.284
# 9 G5     E1      0.606
#10 G5     E2     -0.919
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `...` like this:

```
fn2 <- function(...) list(ge_means1 = fn1(...)$ge_mean)

fn2(df1, Gen, Env, Y)
```

giving:

```
$ge_means1
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups: Gen [?]
   Gen    Env      Mean
   <fctr> <fctr>  <dbl>
 1 G1     E1      0.586
 2 G1     E2     -1.82 
 3 G2     E1      0.709
 4 G2     E2      0.630
 5 G3     E1     -0.109
 6 G3     E2     -0.276
 7 G4     E1     -0.453
 8 G4     E2     -0.284
 9 G5     E1      0.606
10 G5     E2     -0.919
```